# first time app launch intro error (viewpager)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, boolean, splash-screen

i was trying to add some intro screens that would only run only the first time the app is launched, after that it will directly load the login page
i used the following guide to achieve this

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MyPrefs, 0);
    if (sp.getBoolean("first", true)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        /*editor.putBoolean("first", false);*/
        sp.edit().putBoolean("first", false).commit();
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class); //call your ViewPager class
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

But the app skips the intro part and loads the login page when using the app for the first time, and loads the intro pages when launched again
how can i reverse this
thanks

Comment: can you change if (sp.getBoolean("first", true))  to if (sp.getBoolean("first", false)) and lemme know what happenned :) I'll explain you why later :) Though I can suggest a better way to achieve it :) its just a patch to your code :)

Comment: change the condition

Comment: @SandeepBhandari thanks for replying , changing it to false does help to bring the intro screens but they still show up when the app is launched for the next time .

Comment: @7rocker : I have updated my answer please have a look and lemme know if you still have issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MyPrefs, 0);
    if(sp.contains("first"){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class); //call your ViewPager class
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        sp.edit().putBoolean("first", true).commit();
        editor.commit();
    }
```

**Explanation:**
When you launch your app for the first time variable "first" will not be present in shared preferences :) because you `getBoolean` specifies that the default value to return in case "first" not found to be true :) all your code was going for toss :)

Correct way to do it :) 
Check first if "first" key word exists or not ?? If not that means you are launching it for the first time show the intro screens :) but don't forget to enter the key first with value true :)

So next time you launch first key will be present in shared preferences So now you know that you are launching for second time :) you can skip intro and launch login activity :)

Don't bother your self with the value of "first" and all :)  all you need to know is if this key exists or not that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in your condition. Try this code:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MyPrefs, 0);
if (sp.getBoolean("first", true)) {
    sp.edit().putBoolean("first", false).apply();

    // Show Intro Activity
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

First you check whether it is the first time. If it is, then you show the Intro `Activity`. If it isn't the first time then you show the Login `Activity`.

Note I removed some of the SharedPreferences code, part of it was superfluous. I also changed `commit()` to `apply()`.